# How to remove the last comma in an attribute value?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove the last comma from the `data-group` attribute:

```
<div data-groups='["all", "food", "tool",]'></div>
```

I need it like this:

```
<div data-groups='["all", "food", "tool"]'></div>
```

How to do this with jQuery?

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you done so far?

Comment: would be better if you post sample code too...

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
$("div").attr("data-groups", $("div").attr("data-groups").slice(0,-2) + "]");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-groups='["all", "food", "tool",]'></div>
```

or add class

```js
$(".group").attr("data-groups", $(".group").attr("data-groups").slice(0,-2) + "]");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group" data-groups='["all", "food", "tool",]'></div>
```

Comment: This is better than my answer. I forget about `slice` :) though technically you are applying this to every `div` regardless of wether it has the correct attribute or not

Comment: Thanks. Both code are working. Sexy Turnip, Your code is better for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('[data-groups]').each(function() {
    var groups = $(this).data('groups');
    var trimmed = groups.substring(0, groups.length - 2);
   $(this).attr('data-groups', trimmed + ']');
});
```

```css
div:after {
    content: attr(data-groups);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-groups='["all", "food", "tool",]'>Groups </div>
```

Or less readable...

```
$('[data-groups]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('data-groups', $this.data('groups').substring(0, $this.data('groups').length - 2) + ']');
});
```